# Can't run an infinite thread with Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-imaging-library

The code below works, but if i make the thread an infinite loop (by uncommenting the line i=False) the window does'nt show anymore. What Am I missing?
My goal is to keep updating the image while it's shown.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk,Canvas,NW,mainloop
import threading
from time import sleep
from random  import randint
imgx = 512; imgy = 512


def mi_thread():
   global pix
   i=True
   while i:
     #i=False 
     for k in range(imgy):
        pix[k,k]=(randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))  
     sleep(1)

window = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(window, width = imgx, height = imgy, bg = "#000000");canvas.pack()
img2 = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))    

pix = img2.load()
t= threading.Thread(target=mi_thread())
t.start()
imgx =ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
canvas.create_image((0, 0), image = imgx, state = "normal", anchor = NW)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `threading.Thread(target=mi_thread())` you are actually running your function. You need to remove the parentheses and pass the function reference only. ie:

```
threading.Thread(target = mi_thread)
```